# Mat D =(Mat_<double>(3,3)<< 1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0);

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

Can any describe the following code in OpenCV

```
    Mat D =(Mat_<double>(3,3)<< 1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0);
```

What I don't understand is what

```
           Mat_<double>(3,3)
```

will do?

Comment: explicitly creating a 3 by 3 matrix of doubles

Comment: That can best be answered by adding the line `cout << "D = " << D << endl;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mat is a 3x3 matrix containing values of type double.

Google generics and look up use of templates in C++

Answer (score 0):

`Mat` is a variable type, probably a metatype to represent different types of matrices. `Mat_< datatype >(rows,columns)` describes the exact matrix type (single precision, double precision, integer, etc) and its dimensions. the `< >` is the same as when you define the underlying datatype of a vector with `<>`:

```
std::vector<int> newvec;
```